# Need a slack Like Posting Message in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Developed an Chatter Functionality in Angular. I used Typeahead for Selecting a username while Posting

eg: username some text

[image]

, but its not fulfilling my requirement.

Need a slack like Posting where you can add text with multiple user .

eg: @username1 Hi How are You, we @username2  & @username3 are waiting for you.

[image]

Comment: We don't understand your needs. Provide your code please.

Comment: @mistalis : Like in facebook we can tag multiple user's in a comment , i need same same criteria to be used in my application. present situation i used typeahead where only one user can be tagged, i need multiple typeahead on a input box where i can trigger typeahead with @ symbol